# Embedded and Internal CSS not affecting my lists

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am trying to get it so that my ingredients list is green, my equipment is red and my method list is blue. I am trying to use all different types of css to achieve this. My external works fine as that is the red one but, my two types of internal don't seem to change the other lists.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
    <style>
     ol {color: blue; 
         font-style: italic;
        }
    </style>
  <title>Emily's Cooking Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="demo1.css" />
 </head>

<body>
 <h1>Cooking for Students</h1>
  <p>This page will show you how to make basic <b>macaroni</b> with all shop bought ingredients & how to store it properly</p>

  <img src="macaroni.jpg" width="104" height="142">

 <table>
  <tr><td>prep: 5 minutes</td></tr>
  <tr><td>cook: 30 minutes</td></tr>
  <tr><td>difficulty: easy</td></tr>
  <tr><td>quantity made: 3 to 4 meals</td></tr>
 </table>

<h2>ingredients</h2>
 <p>all found in Morrisons supermarkets</p>
  <ul style="color:green;">
    <li>250g pasta</li>
    <li>300g cheese sauce</li>
  </ul>

<h2>equipment</h2> 
  <ul>
    <li>saucepan</li>
    <li>wooden spoon</li>
    <li>oven with hob</li>
    <li>two to three tubs</li>
  </ul>

<h2>method</h2>
  <ol>
    <li>On oven, turn hob to high heat. Fill a large saucepan with water and place on hob, allow water to begin boiling.</li>
    <li>Once water is boiling, put all 250g of pasta into the saucepan and begin stirring with a wooden spoon.</li>
    <li>Boiling pasta for 20 minutes or until soft. Use a knife or fork to test how hard the pasta is.</li>
    <li>Take the saucepan off the hob and turn the hob down to a low heat. Using a sieve, drain all the water out of the saucepan and place pasta back into saucepan.</li>
    <li>Place saucepan back on the hob and add 300g of cheese sauce to saucepan.</li>
    <li>Mix the cheese sauce and pasta for 5 minutes</li>
    <li>Turn hob off. Spread the macaroni into two or three separate tubs and allow them to cool down. Alternatively, you can eat one serving straight after cooking.</li>
    <li>Once cooled down, place in fridge. To eat, place in microwave for 1 minute and a half, stir, then another minute (you can even add grated cheese on top after stirring).</li>
    <li>After two days, move tubs to the freezer, to de-frost, place tub back in fridge and allow for one day of defrosting in fridge before microwaving and serving.</li> 
  </ol>

 <p>Other Recipes:</p>
  <a href="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/best-ever-macaroni-cheese-recipe">BBC GoodFood Macaroni Recipe</a>
 <p></p>
  <a href="https://www.foodnetwork.ca/everyday-cooking/photos/best-macaroni-recipes/">Food Network Macaroni Recipes</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you posted works as expected, the `ol` list items are displayed in blue and italic, also the green `ul` is displayed in green.

Answer (score 0):

The following rule applies to all ordered lists.

```
ol {
  color: blue; 
  font-style: italic;
}
```

Therefore, all `ol` should have blue color.

The ingredients list is a `ul` and has the inline styling of green color:

```
<ul style="color:green;">
  <li>250g pasta</li>
  <li>300g cheese sauce</li>
</ul>
```

Following your way, in order to apply the red color to the equipment list you can write:

```
<ul style="color: red">
  <li>saucepan</li>
  <li>wooden spoon</li>
  <li>oven with hob</li>
  <li>two to three tubs</li>
</ul>
```

However, I would suggest to create three classes for each color.

For example,

```
.color-blue {
  color: blue;
}

.color-red {
  color: red;
}

.color-green {
  color: green;
}
```

```
<ul class="color-green;">
  <li>250g pasta</li>
  <li>300g cheese sauce</li>
</ul>

<ul class="color-red;">
  <li>saucepan</li>
  <li>wooden spoon</li>
  <li>oven with hob</li>
  <li>two to three tubs</li>
</ul>

<ol class="color-blue">
  <li>On oven, turn hob to high heat. Fill a large saucepan with water and place on hob, allow water to begin boiling.</li>
 ...
 ...
</ol>
```